# Geoserver GeoWebCache AntiAlias LargePolygon Error OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

When using geoserver (1.7.X) and OpenLayers (WMS layer) togheter I get a weird behavour if a render several layers with antialias and one of the bottom layers is really large compared to the rest of the features in the layers "on top". 
[image]

The background should have been not black.

If I go straight to the geoserver and disable antialias I get correct but when I try to use the geowebcache I have not found any way to make sure that the format_options=antialias:none is used when Geowebcache asks the geoserver for the tile.

According to some documentation there is a vendor tag in geowebcache but I can't see any effect on then antialiasing.

Anyone who have a succesful go at format_options in the vendor tag in geowebcache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't come up with an answer but Arne Kep from the geowebcache-users mail list did.

Inserting FORMAT_OPTIONS=antialias:none

right above

/cache/XXX
in the geowebcache.xml was the place to modify.